# Extend sitecore's IncludeItemForDisplay to types other than TreeList

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I am looking for an easy way to extend the `IncludeTemplatesForDisplay` to types other than `TreeList`.  I am using Sitecore 6.4. Typically I use a droptree` when I only want to select one item, but then it appears like I can't filter the display.

I can see where I could alter the Sitecore code, but I'd rather take a patching approach rather than editing the `sitecore.client.dll`.  I've overridden handlers in the `<sitecore>` sections in the config before, but a place to override this functionality is not jumping out at me.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at the `getDatasourceItems` pipeline, a solution like in this blog: http://newguid.net/sitecore/2013/coded-field-datasources-in-sit
ecore/, or the standard sitecore query format: `query:/sitecore/content/home/*[@@templatename='Section']`.

Hope this helps.